# Unity Xml configuration for Nhibernate IsessionFactory

Tags: c#, nhibernate, unity-container, xml-configuration

I resolved session factory using code as

```
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISessionFactory),
                new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory());
```

My service which defines property as

```
public class myService
{
   [Dependency]
   public ISessionFactory SessionFactory{get;set;}
}
```

But don't know how to configure this using XML configuration of unity 2.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, this answer is more related to the content discussed in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730411/1679310 (comments)

Let me provide you with more details, related to your mapping.

Firstly, reduce full names:

```
// here we have namespace, not needed below for classes, if is the same
<hibernate-mapping  ... namespace="NhibernateTesting.Models" >
```

The original class mapping is commented, my approach is replacing it:

```
// <class name="NhibernateTesting.Models.ProductList" table="ProductList" lazy="false">    
<class name="ProductList" table="ProductList" 
  lazy="true" // always use LAZY
  batch-size="25" // optimization for loading - avoid 1 + N
>

//<id name="Id">
//  <generator class="native" />
//</id>
// more readable version
<id name="Id" generator="native" />

// these are OK
<property name="Name" />
<property name="Owner" />

// collection should be ALWAYS lazy
// <bag name="Viewers" table="ProductListViewer" lazy="false">
// and also, optimization as batch size is needed
<bag name="Viewers" table="ProductListViewer" 
  lazy="true" // LAZY is must, 
  batch-size="25" cool optimization to avoid 1 + N
>
  <key column="ProductListId" />
  <element column="Username" type="System.String"/>
</bag>

// I would never use MANY-TO-MANY
// <bag name="Products" table="ProductListProductXRef" lazy="false" cascade="all" fetch="select">
<bag name="Products" table="ProductListProductXRef" 
   inverse="true" // in many to many only one side could be inverse
   lazy="true" 
   cascade="none"  // cascade here means, delete PRODUCTS
                  // not the pairing table, so I would expect that we need none
   fetch="select">
  <key column="ProductListId" />

  // I would avoid many to many if possible
  <many-to-many column="ProductId" class="NhibernateTesting.Models.Product" />
 ...
```

Check these links for more details.

#### Laziness

- [NHibernate When to Use lazy loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27164685/1679310)

#### Batch fetching

- [NHibernate always hydrates many-to-one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085151/1679310)
- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)

#### Avoid many to many

- [many-to-many with extra columns nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22563082/1679310)
- [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15510748/1679310)

#### When to use cascading

- [nhibernate - Create child by updating parent, or create explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28030426/1679310)

These would be my suggestions, which apply to all mappings.

In general this should be the class mapping

```
<class 
  name="ProductList" 
  table="ProductList" 
  lazy="true"
  batch-size="25"
>
```

In case we need versioning:

```
<class 
  name="ProductList" 
  table="ProductList" 
  lazy="true"
  batch-size="25"
  optimistic-lock="version" 
  dynamic-update="true" 
>

<version name="Timestamp" generated="always" unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">
  <column name="RowVersion" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp"/>
</version>
```

This should be the collection mapping:

```
<bag name="Items" 
   lazy="true" 
   inverse="true" 
   batch-size="25" 
   cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="Item_ID" />
  <one-to-many class="SomeItemClass"/>
</bag>
```